# MATLAB: Colors displayed incorrectly?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have noticed that MATLAB sometimes displays my colors incorrectly. I'm not sure if this is a programming error on my side, or if it is an actual bug in MATLAB. I noticed this behavior with some regularity over the last year or so.

This time, I decided to take a snapshot of a figure with the error in question (taken on MATLAB 2011b on Windows 7, 64 bit):

[image]

The code that displays the image in question is the following:

```
figure;
clf;
cla;
imshow(matrix, []);
colormap(cmap);
set(gca, 'Clim', [0 highest_index]);
```

where:

- `matrix` is of type `uint32` (although I have also tried explitly casting `matrix` as `double` prior to calling `imshow`)
- The values in `matrix` range between `0` and `900`
- `cmap` has `901` entries
- `highest_index` is `900`

The RGB entry for the value `259` in `matrix` is `[1, 0, 0.1]` both in the image above and in the colormap array `cmap`, i.e. `cmap(300, :) = [1, 0, 0.1]` (notice that the matrix value `259` gets the index `300` in the colormap, since the first entry of the colormap is for the matrix value `0`).

### Questions:

Why does this happen? Is it an error? Is there anything I am doing wrong?

### Update 1:

1. I tried switching `CDataMapping` to `direct` or `scaled`, but it didn't make a difference.
2. I also tried using `imagesc` instead of `imshow`, but it didn't make a difference.
3. If I convert the image to RGB first (i.e. transform the `indexed image` to a `true color` image; [see here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html) for more info on this), i.e. with `i_rgb = ind2rgb(i_indexed, cmap)`, the error goes away and the image is displayed **correctly**.

   Unfortunately, if I display a `true color` image the data tip does not reveal the index in the original matrix for each color anymore and instead it just displays the RGB vector (i.e. this is logical, since MATLAB is not aware of the original index anymore).

### Update 2:

Here's some sample code:

```
h_f = figure(1);
clf;
i_spiral = spiral(40);
h_i = image(i_spiral);

% Synthesize a colormap first in HSV and then transform it to RGB:
max_i_spiral = max(i_spiral(:));
m           = max_i_spiral;
h           = (0:m-1)'/max(m,1);
cmap_spiral = hsv2rgb([h ones(m,2)]);  
colormap(cmap_spiral);

% If I comment out the following two lines or use imshow instead of image, 
% it makes no difference (I still get the same error):
set(gca, 'Clim', [1 max_i_spiral]);
set(h_i, 'CDataMapping', 'direct');
```

The code above results in:

[image]

Comment: can you post an actual example that we can reproduce with code?

Comment: Thanks @Amro. I have included an example in my 2nd Update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Since this answer is totally unrelated to my former answer, I'm not editing the first]

The link you mention (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html)
says:

> **Note**   When using the painters renderer on the Windows platform, you should only use 256 colors when attempting to display an indexed
>   image. Larger colormaps can lead to unexpected colors because the
>   painters algorithm uses the Windows 256 color palette, which graphics
>   drivers and graphics hardware are known to handle differently. To work
>   around this issue, use the Zbuffer or OpenGL renderer, as appropriate.
>   For more information regarding graphics renderers in MATLAB, see
>   Technical Note 1201: [The Technical Support Guide to Graphics Rendering
>   and Troubleshooting](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1200/1201.html).

So it seems the problem is that your colormap has more then 256 values. It also explains why the problem goes away if you don't use an indexed image. Try using a different renderer, as suggested in the technical support link from the note:

```
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'opengl')
```

or

```
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'Zbuffer')
```

Comment: Thanks Itamar. This fixes it! It also makes me wonder why `colormap` doesn't switch automatically to `Zbuffer` or `OpenGL` when the colormap has more than `256` entries  on a `pc` (`basicImageDisplay` which is called by `imshow` switches to `zbuffer` if it is aware of the colormap and it's on a pc; see my comment on @Amro's answer)

Comment: Thanks, but I was only following @intrpc's link.

Answer (score 3):

A better way to use [IMSHOW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html) is:

```
imshow(img,map)
```

Here is your example slightly rewritten:

```
%# indexed image
I = spiral(40);

%# Synthesize a colormap first in HSV and then transform it to RGB
mx = max(I(:));
cmap = hsv2rgb([(0:mx-1)'./max(mx,1) ones(mx,2)]);         %'

%# show image
imshow(I,cmap)
colorbar
datacursormode on
```

[image: screenshot]

---

#### EDIT:

Thanks to [@ItamarKatz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774342/matlab-colors-displayed-incorrectly/7785911#7785911), we now know that on Windows, if you are displaying an indexed image with more than 256 colors, one must not use the 'painters' algorithm as renderer.

IMSHOW (which underneath calls the lower level IMAGE function), detects such a case and correctly handles it.

If you still want to use IMAGE/IMAGESC, you must be aware of the indexed image data type:

- **double**:
  Image contains integers in the range `[1 length(cmap)]` as indices in the current colormap
- **uint8/uint16**:
  Image contains integers in the range `[0 255]` for `uint8` or `[0 65535]` for `uint16`, interpreted as indices in the current colormap.

thus there is an offset (range starts at `0` or `1`) which you should be careful about.

Here is the same example as above using IMAGE function directly (once with double data type, the other with uint16):

```
%# indexed image and colormap
I = spiral(40);
cmap = hsv( max(I(:)) );

%# show indexed image (double)
hFig = figure(2);
hImg = image(I);                          %# one-based index into colormap
colormap(cmap), colorbar
axis off image

%# fix bug on Windows with indexed image of more than 256 colors
if ispc && strcmpi(get(hImg,'CDataMapping'),'direct') && size(cmap,1) > 256
    set(hFig, 'Renderer','zbuffer')       %# opengl renderer also works
end

%# show indexed image (uint16)
hFig = figure(3);
hImg = image( uint16(I-1) );              %# zero-based index into colormap
colormap(cmap), colorbar
axis off image

%# fix bug on Windows with indexed image of more than 256 colors
if ispc && strcmpi(get(hImg,'CDataMapping'),'direct') && size(cmap,1) > 256
    set(hFig, 'Renderer','zbuffer')
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Amro, your solution works. Your answer made me wonder why  your call to `imshow` with an explicit colormap in the function call works, whereas mine in the OP doesn't. With this, I went and looked at the code of `imshow` and I saw that that it calls `basicImageDisplay`, which itself switches the rendering engine to `Zbuffer` if `imshow` is aware of the fact that there is colormap. With all this, I think I'll accept @Itamar's solution, since it addresses the root of the problem and lets me use either syntax

Comment: @intrpc: I added a note about the data type of indexed image when calling the IMAGE function

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure (couldn't verify without your data), but I think the reason is wrong mapping/rounding done by the data-tip display function callback. You can create your own callback, by right-clicking the data tip, selecting `Edit Text Update Function...`, and entering something like that:

```
function output_txt = dataCursorCallback(obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor, and the RGB data to 6 decimal places.

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
    ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)]};

h = get(event_obj,'target');
cdata = get (h, 'CData');
cmap = colormap;
rgb = cmap(cdata(pos(2),pos(1)),:);
output_txt{end+1} = ['RGB: ' num2str(rgb,'%.6f')];
```

Note that the above code assumes the colormap length and and data range of the matrix plotted are the same - like in your example.
To save the callback, click `save and close`, and you can re-select it on next occasions by right-clicking the data tip and selecting `Select Text Update Function...`

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try. Not sure I fully understood your comment though. The color entry in my colormap for the matrix value `259` is `[1, 0, 0.1]`, and I built the colormap myself. Also, the color is displayed incorrectly regardless of whether or not I have a datatip... With this, do you still think your answer may address my question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the color itself, only the value in the data tip, which is different from the entry you mention. Can you paste the code you use to create the colormap? Does this problem happens also when you use `imagesc`, or only with `imshow`?

Comment: Thanks @Itamar. I'll try to write a small code snippet that builds the colormap and matrix and reproduces the error on my machine. In the mean time, I have updated my OP with some tests that I have done.